# hook_menu, display a form at the top and table at the bottom

Tags: 7, routes

I'm a bit lost trying to create a page with hook_menu that displays a form and a table below it. Preferably the table should only be displayed after the form has been submitted, but that's not the main issue.

I don't have any issue with displaying the table or the form, but I can't get it to be displayed at the same time on the same page.

I have a `my_module_table()` function that ends with

```
...
return theme('table', array( 'header' => $header,  'rows'=> $rows  ) );
```

I then have a function for the form `my_module_form($form, &$form_state)`

I then have this function to put both of these functions in an array

```
function my_module_page() {
  $output = array();
  $output['form'] = drupal_get_form('my_module_form');
  $output['table'] = 'my_module_table';
  return $output;
}
```

Than last I try to create the page and get both the form and the table to render on the page using **hook_menu**

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['mymodule'] = array(
    'title' => 'My module',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

I don't have any issues with the form or table functions, they work fine if I don't try to render both at ones.

Can anybody tel me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of getting the table data into the output array as $output['table'], why not get the table into the form as a markup element and displaying the form as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this:

```
$output['table'] = 'my_module_table';
```

To this:

```
  $output['table'] = my_module_table();
```

Also note that this:

```
...
return theme('table', array( 'header' => $header,  'rows'=> $rows  ) );
```

Can be this:

```
...
return array (
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => t('Nothing found. Nada. Zip. Zilch.'),
);
```

This will add this fragment to the render array you are creating in my_module_page(), meaning it can be overridden further down the line if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of my earlier suggestion to append the table as a form markup and rendering the form with table in the menu callback

```
/**
 * Form builder function
 */
function mymodule_form() {
  $form = array();
  $form['sometext'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Some random textfield'),
    '#default_value' => 'Hello world',
  );
  $form['tablemarkup'] = array(
    '#markup' => my_module_table(),
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}


/**
 * Callback function for returning form with themed table
 */
function mymodule_page() {
  $output = array();
  $form_data = drupal_get_form('my_module_form');
  $output = drupal_render($form_data);
  return $output;
}

/**
 * Function to return themed table.
 */
function my_module_table() {
  $header = array(
    'data' => 'Table title',
  );
  $rows[] = array(
    'Table data value',
  );
  return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows'=> $rows));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and give me this solution, it helped me work out this issue :) You helped me keep myself sane for little longer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your output to a [renderable array](https://drupal.org/node/930760) for starters, but you could try something like

```
$output = render(drupal_get_form('my_module_form'));
$output .= my_module_table();
```

i think it will work, edited.

Comment: It won't - `drupal_get_form()` returns an array...

Comment: @Clive correct. - edited

Comment: I'm just being picky now, but you should do it like this: `$form = drupal_get_form('my_module_form'); $output = drupal_render($form);`, otherwise you'll get warnings about passing by reference